# Entity Framework on .mdf file

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am working on some project at the moment and I have to use local database. So, I created a new service-based database (no tables atm). Then I wanted to add Entity Framework support.

Because I never used Entity Framework before, I was referring to that link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj200620.aspx.

Everything is OK, but here it gets complicated. I created my `DataContext` class with `DbSet` inside it. But, when I run my unit test, table is created on Localdb (not inside my `.mdf` file).

What to do?

I am pretty sure, that I did choose which database to use correctly (actually did that 3 times already), but still, data tables are created on LocalDb. What I am doing wrong here?

I am complete beginner with that (been only using doctrine ORM). Otherwise I can insert data and all, it is just on the wrong database.

Comment: Is your unit tests on a seperate project with a different app.config? This seems to be related to a connection string issue.

Comment: Yes, it is. But I also copied the same app.config I am using inside DataAccess project into this UnitTest project.

Comment: Are you using code first?

Comment: Yes, I am using code first.

Comment: @Orochi Had very similar problem in the past. I can't remember exactly the solution, but the cause was the usage of multiple `.config` files across the solution. I'm not sure why, but sometimes the `VS` defaults to the `localdb` connection string even though you have passed different in the `DbContext` constructor. So just play around with the `connection` string across your solution comment/delete and try and I'm pretty sure you'll find the right set up. It's just a matter of where to put your desired connection string and where to not have one at all!

Comment: It's much likely to be wrong but I remember something along the lines that if you use multiple projects in your solution (like if you have `DataAccessLayer` for instance) you need to define a connection string only in the `app.config` file of the startup project. As I said, this may very well not be true, but just to let you know how I made it work for me.

Comment: Well, I just created a simple solution with one project and still the same. It must be something with connection string i guess. This is, how it looks like: connectionString="data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework"

Comment: @orochi - in that case make sure your referencing the actual connection string name you need in a base call to the parent class in your EF Data context Ctor, then all you need to do is specify one conn str in your web.config and it will always go to the source you tell it to.  Let me find a few details I'll write it up properly.

Comment: Actually, in fact I'll point you at a blog post I did previously on the subject.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When your doing code first development in EF, you can force EF to only ever consider one connection string name.

One of the constructors (of which there are quite a few overloads) on the EF Data Context parent classes, takes a simple string.

This string is given to be the name of a connection string in the App or Web config to use.

You make the call something like this:

```
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace MSSQL_EFCF.Classes
{
  public class DataAccess : DbContext
  {
    public DataAccess() : base("myConnectionString")
    {}

    public DbSet<MyTableObject> MyObjects { get; set; }

  }
}
```

You can still put any code you need for your own start-up (Such as DB Initializer calls) inside your constructor, and all that will get called once the base call completes.

The advantage of doing things this way forces entity framework to always use the named connection string and never anything else.

The reason this catches many developers out, and why it runs off an uses localdb is deceptively simple.

The Entity Framework DbContext by default will use the name of the data context derived class as a database name, and if it can't find a suitable connection string in any config file by that name, makes the assumption that your working in development mode without a full backing data store.

In my example above, EF would examine App and/or Web.config for a connection string called "myConnectionString"

Once it makes this development decision, it knows that localdb will be present as this gets installed with the latest builds of visual studio, and so it will automatically seek out a connection and populate it with a db that follows the name of the context in which it's used.

I've previously written a blog post on the subject, which you can find here :

http://www.codeguru.com/columns/dotnet/entity-framework-code-first-simplicity.htm

**NOTE:** The above applies to any database that you connect with using EF, it's the connection string that decides what/where the actual data store is.