# How to put ASP.NET Json WebHelper object into a database

Tags: asp.net, razor

I want to take the data from my json file, parse and send to my database. Each field in my json objects have to go to it's corresponding column in my table. I don't have SQL Server 2016 so I need to do this in my ASP.NET Webpages site using razor. I was able to get the file data and I used Json.Decode to make it a object I guess?? Here is how I got the JSON file data

```
@{
Layout = "~/_SiteLayout.cshtml";

var json =File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/enforcement_actions.json"));
var data = Json.Decode(json);
```

}
I am completely lost from this point as far as now taking the 'data' variable, parse, and send to my database file. Any help would be great.

Comment: Are you trying to connect to the database from view? If yes, you should use Controller to do that. What database are you using?

Comment: I'm using WebPages so I'm connecting to the database Database.Open"~/App_Data/Database.mdf"  I wanted to pretty much write some razor code to put the json object into the database. I know there are a lot of steps in between so any advice would help.

Answer (score 0):

Look for Entity Framework and mdf file here: [Entity Framework on .mdf file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26195466/entity-framework-on-mdf-file)

After that, you have to look to how to map classes on Entity Framework. You see  that here: [How to map an Entity framework model to a table name dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428069/how-to-map-an-entity-framework-model-to-a-table-name-dynamically)

And finally you'll save your data on the database. You can see it here: [Insert data using Entity Framework model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835434/insert-data-using-entity-framework-model)