# EF migrations won't recognize existing tables

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I've set up this project from DB first and everything went fine. I can debug properly. But when I try make a change to one of my models, instead of the new migration showing a simple AlterColumn statement, it keeps trying to reinitialize the entire database.

I've tried running update database -script and only inserting the _MigrationHistory table record. Even after that, it still wants to create all the tables.

Has this ever happened to anyone?

Comment: what is the database initializer you use? Probably DropCreateDatabaseWhenModelChanges?

Comment: I can't find an initializer declared anywhere.

Comment: Try to find `Database.SetInitializer` in your code. There you will find the initializer type you are using. By default it is `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists` but behavior of your app tends to `DropCreateDatabaseWhenModelChanges` like DevilSuichiro wrote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you start with an existing database you need to do an empty (no-op) migration to set a baseline. This is because EF will use the model in the prior migration to compare, so if there is not one (in code) you get all your database objects. Inserting a record into __MigrationHistory just tells EF the code migration has been applied - it doesn't use it for the compare.

> enable-migrations
>
> add-migration MyBaseline -IgnoreChanges       // no Up() code, but model saved
>
> update-database
>
> // Now I can change my model and generate a migration with difference

See [here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn579398.aspx#option1)

Comment: so before doing this should I clear out my MigrationHistory table?

Comment: Yes, clear the table and roll back the model changes you made after you reverse engineered if possible. If the changes are extensive since the import you could just comment out the Up() code of the existing objects.

Comment: Tried deleting all rows from _MigrationHistory and running empty migration. Got back an error that the system could not find some .mdf file. I didn't think it should be looking at an .mdf file?

Comment: What error at what step? An MDF file is a database file. If your database exists and the connection string is correct you should not get that.

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Directory lookup for the file "C:\L360\L360.Web\App_Data\L360.Data.L360Context.mdf" failed with the operating system error 2(The system cannot find the file specified.).

that App_Data folder doesn't even exist. I'm not sure where it's set so that it's looking there.

Comment: I also tried just inserting the record in to MigrationHistory indicating that I've updated the database with my blank Baseline migration. When I tried adding another migration it told me I needed to apply the pending migration "Baseline". I thought having the row in MigrationHistory would sort of make it be seen as having been applied.

Comment: Doing update-database or generating a script should insert the record for you. Has your app ever been up and running prior to migrations? Looks like you need to straighten out your connection string and initializer before you worry about migrations.

Comment: My app is up and running. It was an old ASP.NET project that I'm converting over. The rewrite of the code is currently working pointing against the existing database. This is one of three products my group is developing using this framework and none of the other ones have this problem. Granted, none of the others were built from an existing database.

Comment: OK, so focus on migrations. You were able to enable-migrations, add-migration but you get the error on update-database? You are migrating from the console and you have the proper project selected in the dropdown? If __MigrationHistory was created it must have done an update-database or script at some point.

Comment: You could also just reset migrations by removing the Migrations folder from project and dropping the __MigrationHistory table.

Comment: The .mdf issue was because my InstitutionContext constructor had an invalid connection string name. Found that answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26195466/entity-framework-on-mdf-file. Once I sorted that out, applying the empty baseline migration allowed me to have normal migrations after that. Thank you so much for your help.

As a point of clarity, do all DB first projects need to keep their migrations in project for reference? Our other projects don't do that.

Comment: Point of clarity: DB first is different. This is code first to an existing database. Migrations are one way to keep the model in sync, but there are others like database projects that do a diff and generate scripts. Once your PROD database is updated you could role your migrations up as described here. http://cpratt.co/migrating-production-database-with-entity-framework-code-first/#at_pco=smlwn-1.0&at_si=54ad5c7b61c48943&at_ab=per-12&at_pos=0&at_tot=1